# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el valor de una variable de Node.js en un documento HTML?

Tags: nodejs

Soy bastante nuevo en Node.js y lo estoy utilizando para hacer Web Scraping con una extensión llamada Puppeteer, realmente necesito que la variable que almacena el valor al scrapear el valor de la web, ese valor se muestre en un documento HTML pero no sé cómo lograrlo.

Lo que tengo es esto:

```
getPrice();
function getPrice() {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const fs = require('fs');
        void (async () => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
            const page = await browser.newPage()              
            await page.goto('http://example.com')
            await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 938 })        
            await page.waitForSelector('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button')
            await page.click('.m-hotel-info > .l-container > .l-header-section > .l-m-col-2 > .m-button')
            await page.waitForSelector('.modal-content')
            await page.click('.tile-hsearch-hws > .m-search-tabs > #edit-search-panel > .l-em-reset > .m-field-wrap > .l-xs-col-4 > .analytics-click')
            await page.waitForNavigation();
            await page.waitForSelector('.tile-search-filter > .l-display-none')
            const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.tile-search-filter > .l-display-none').innerText);
            console.log(innerText)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }       
    })()
}
```

Y lo que me interesa es que se muestre el valor de la variable innerText en un documento HTML para que pueda ser visualizado a través de un navegador y no a través de la línea de comandos.

He tratado de abrirlo cómo si se tratara de un código JavaScript en mi navegador, pero me da error en el require ya que por lo que me han dicho, Node.js no es posible ejecutarlo a través de un navegador web.

La verdad no sé que hacer, hasta he tratado de hacerlo a través de un .bat y generar un archivo html con el resultado de ejecutar node scraper.js pero no me funcionó.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Node.js se esta ejecutando en el server mientras que el HTML en el cliente. Vas a tener que conectarlos mediante una petición ajax de cliente a servidor y que en la respuesta de esa llamada venga el valor que quieres mostrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa un editor de templates como EJS o pug para NODE

Te dejo la referencia a [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs)

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Con EJS me ha funcionado perfectamente, aunque también he tenido que usar [express](https://expressjs.com/) para poder enviar los resultados a mi plantilla EJS y para pasarle parámetros.

Comment: Si claro ejs corre es en el servidor de Node y se maneja mejor con express